# Compare attribute of one element to attribute of another element

Tags: xpath

This seems like it should be easy, but I can never figure it out.

Presume I have the following document:

```
<data>
    <a>
       <b val="1"/>
    </a>
    <c val="1">
</data>
```

And assume that I am executing an XPath from the context of `<b>`. I need to check if there is an element `c` that has the same value as `b`.

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
../a/c[@val=@val]
```

How to I get an XPath to remember its "current" context when traversing the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the expression below.  You'll notice that the current node is not lost since a predicate is used for finding the `c` node.

```
.[../../c/@val=@val]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!