# XPath to find elements that have no other elements referencing them

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri

Given the following XML document…

```xml
<r>
  <e id="a" />
  <e id="b" />
  <e id="c" />
  <x ref="#b" />
</r>
```

…how can I write an XPath 1.0 expression that finds all `<e>` elements that do not have an `<x>` element referencing them? In this example, the result should be `#a` and `#c`.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20590592/405017) I tried `//e[ not(//x[@ref=concat("#",@id)]) ]`, but this does not omit the referenced element:

```ruby
# Ruby code using Nokogiri
puts doc.xpath( '//e[ not(//x[@ref=concat("#",@id)]) ]' )
#=> <e id="a"/>
#=> <e id="b"/>
#=> <e id="c"/>
```

Is there a way to use an attribute in the found set to further query the values of other attributes in other elements?

Comment: Note that in Ruby you can accomplish this as a multiple pass via `doc.xpath('//e').reject{ |e| doc.at("//x[@ref='##{e['id']}']") }`; this question is about a single XPath expression to find the right set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From this XML**

```
<r>
  <e id="a" />
  <e id="b" />
  <e id="c" />
  <x ref="#b" />
</r>
```

**this XPath**

```
//e[ not(//x/@ref=concat("#",@id)) ]
```

**will select**

```
<e id="a"/>
<e id="c"/>
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Do you happen to have a reference in the XPath spec that would describe the scoping rules for how an attribute is resolved? And...wow, I've never seen an equality assertion outside a predicate.

Comment: [**XPath predicates**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) are defined relative to a context node.  The problem you were having was that you established `x` as the context for `@ref` **and** `@id` at the same time when you really only wanted `x` to be the context for `@ref` and `e` to be the context for `@id`.

Comment: @Phrogz I think the equality _is_ inside the predicate, it’s pretty much the same as `//e[not(concat("#", @id) = //x/@ref)]` which I was just about to post as an answer before seeing I was beaten to it, but shows that the equality is comparing the result of `concat` to the `//x/@ref` nodeset. The [part of the spec on booleans and comparisons](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) is also pretty relevant here.

Comment: @matt Well, I just discovered that I can select `//e/@id = 'a'` and get a boolean result, which is what this is using. So while it happens to be inside an outer predicate, it does not have to be.